# hive sql subset based on first value and unique group

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have the following table sorted in a specific manner (in HiveSQL):

```
ID Binary UnnecessaryVar
1    F          a
1    F          b
1    T          c
1    F          d
2    F          e
2    T          f 
2    F          g
```

I would like to select all rows FOR EACH ID before the first T in Binary variable, including the record where the variable is T. The result of the solution applied to the table above would be:

```
ID Binary UnnecessaryVar
1    F          a
1    F          b
1    T          c
2    F          e
2    T          f
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: There are no such thing as _first_ in tables. You need to specify the order to be able to find a first row.

Comment: What if there is no `T`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff in that case, it should take all records that are false

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is not "ordering" without a column to specify it.  If you have an `order by` clause, you can easily add such an ordering:

```
select . . . ,
       row_number() over (order by <keys used in order by>) as seqnum
. . .
```

So let me assume you have such a column.  Here is a pretty simple method:

```
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             min(case when binary = 'T' then seqnum end) over 
                 (partition by id) as seqnum_t
      from <your query here> q
     ) q
where seqnum <= seqnum_t or seqnum_t is null;
```

Comment: of course the dataset is ordered in a specific/meaningful manner, it is just nor relevant to the task, you can even create the column if needed ( row number for example would suffice). I will try this now and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: Should the alias in the first row of your query be t.* ?